# Tomar el valor de una columna en sharepoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online

actualmente estoy haciendo mi trabajo de diploma en una plataforma SharePoint, instrumento que nunca antes habia utilizado.
Los usuarios me pidieron un metodo para comparar dos campos de texto RTF, para hacerlo cree mi proprio editor de texto en un iframe y utilize la libreria DiffMatchPatch, ahora el problema es en la implementacion, tendria que rellenar el iframe con el valor de la columna RTF que contiene las informaciones que tienen que ser comparadas.

buscando en internet encontre distintas soluciones, pero ninguna me funciono, 
el ultimo pedazo de codigo que utilize es el siguiente :

```
<script>
        $SP().list("1").get({
            fields: "id,corpo",
            where: 'id = "1"'
        },
        function getData(data){
            console.log(data + " data");
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                var frame = document.getElementById("theWYSIWYG");
                frame.contentWindow.document.body.innerText = data[i].getAttribute("corpo");
                console.log(data[i].getAttribute("corpo"));
            }
        });
    </script>
```

utilize el content editor para insertar mi codigo html, ahora, como hago para  tomar en algun modo (si es posible) el campo deseado del elemento actual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

encontrè la solucion, la condivido en caso alguien necesite :

```
 SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', sharePointReady);
 function sharePointReady() {
        // se carga el el contexto del web
        clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        //se elije la lista 
        list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Prova Scheda");
        //tomamos el id del campo deseado tramite el url
        var itemId = parseInt(GetUrlKeyValue('ID'));
        item = list.getItemById(itemId);
        //y en fin pedimos la informacion 
        clientContext.load(item);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSucceeded, onRequestFailed);
    }
    function onRequestSucceeded() {
        corpo = item.get_item('Corpo');
        corpoOr = item.get_item('CorpoOriginale');

        text2 = corpo.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
        text1 = corpoOr.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
        text1 = text1.replace("&#160;","");
        text2 = text2.replace("&#160;","");


        var lista1 = dividi(text1);
        var lista2 = dividi(text2);

        $("#ctl00_ctl40_g_d316305f_70e1_4db0_b75a_312430a68b7b_FormControl0_V1_I1_RTC5_RTI1_RT1_newRichText").html(DIFF.diff_prettyHtml(lista1));
        $("#ctl00_ctl40_g_d316305f_70e1_4db0_b75a_312430a68b7b_FormControl0_V1_I1_RTC6_RTI6_RT1_newRichText").html(DIFF.diff_prettyHtml(lista2));
        $("#ctl00_ctl40_g_d316305f_70e1_4db0_b75a_312430a68b7b_FormControl0_V1_I1_RTC6_RTI3_RT1_newRichText").html(DIFF.diff_prettyHtml(lista2));
    }
    function onRequestFailed(sender, args) {
        console.log('Error: ' + args.get_message());
    }
```